# label when the screen is big

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a label with many lines of text. I want to have 20px of margin on left and right if the screen is small but I do not want it to be bigger than 300px if the screen is big.

What I have tried:
- I choose a label as I want the text to be not scrollable and not selectable
- I have given it Attributes > Lines > 0. To adapt to many lines
- I have given it constraints to top, left and right

I am very new to Xcode. In html I would use something like that css:

```
.text {
  with:90%;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

How could I create a similar effect in Xcode and Swift?
(The left and right constrains works well for me to give a similar effect to the width:90% in a small screen. What I am asking now is how to limit the width of the label if the screen is big. Please, be aware that I am very new to Xcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you'd want to use less than and greater than constraints.

Set the following constraints:

- width ≤ 300
- left ≥ safe area left + 20
- right ≥ safe area right - 20
- horizontally in container = 0
- top = 20

You can add a ≤ or ≥ constraint by selecting the constraint and using the drop down that says "Relation" in the property inspector:

[image]

Comment: In Storyboard if I click to Add New Constraints I see Width and I can put 300 but I do no see how to put  ≤300. How can I do that? (Sorry, I know it must seem a stupid question but I am an absolute beginner)

Comment: If the width is for instance 400. That solution does not work well in small phones as it does not give the left and right margins on small phones and portrate mode

Comment: @segon It should give a left and right margin of 20 on phones of any size, no? What does it do on small phones?

Comment: On small screens, it does not respect the 20px of left and right margins. In fact, in all phones portrait mode

Comment: @segon That's weird... Does the view in question have any other siblings that might affect how it is positioned? Try changing the left and right margins to ≥ and the priority to required?